# Having problem with a "Search" button in C# form connected to my MariaDB. Can anyone help me form a query?

Tags: c#, winforms, mariadb

I've got a WinForm app that has a GridView connected to my MariaDB along with TextBoxes and DateTimePickers that correspond to each column in MariaDB database. I want to make a "Search" button that returns a matching value I choose to search with (so any of the date/string columns in this case). I've only got my query to work with string options but Date options are not. I know the problem is in my query so if there's anyone that could help me out I'd be really grateful.

Here's the code for the "Search" button so far.

```
private void btnPretrazi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MariaDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection konekcija = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
        konekcija.Open();
        string upit = "SELECT * FROM radninalog WHERE opisNaloga LIKE @OpisNaloga AND (inzenjerNaloga LIKE @InzenjerNaloga OR DATE(datumNaloga) = @DatumNaloga OR DATE(planiraniPocDatum) = @PlaniraniPocDatum OR DATE(planiraniKrajDatum) = @PlaniraniKrajDatum OR DATE(stvarniPocDatum) = @StvarniPocDatum OR DATE(stvarniKrajDatum) = @StvarniKrajDatum)";
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(upit, konekcija))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OpisNaloga", "%" + opisNalogaTextBox.Text + "%");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatumNaloga", dateTimePicker1.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InzenjerNaloga", "%" + inzenjerNalogaTextBox.Text + "%");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlaniraniPocDatum", dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlaniraniKrajDatum", dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StvarniPocDatum", dateTimePicker4.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StvarniKrajDatum", dateTimePicker5.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

            DataTable radniNalog = new DataTable();
            using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                adapter.Fill(radniNalog);
            }
            radniNalogGridView.DataSource = radniNalog;
        }
    }
    metode.OcistiUnose(this);
}
```

The last line is just a method to clear all entries in the database.

Comment: `Parameters.AddWithValue` will infer the parameter type of the object passed as the `value` argument, so when you add`dateTimePicker5.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`, you are passing a string object so you'll end up with a string parameter type (`varchar` presumably). At a guess (because "doesn't work" is a fairly broad description of a problem) this is causing casting issues in your query, you should just be able to pass a DateTime object to get a DateTime parameter, e.g. `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlaniraniPocDatum", dateTimePicker2.Value);`

Comment: @GarethD The reason it's formatted to "yyyy-MM-dd" is because that's the DATE format for MariadDB, whereas for C# Form it's "dd-MM-yyyy" for me (think it's dependant on your PC region, not sure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reproduce your issue by creating a minimal example where I have three controls in the form, namely `dtpDate`, `btnSearch` (Search button) and `dataGridView1`. When you click the Search button the program performs a select query from the `ColDate` column in the `TblEvent` table. The `ColDate` column is of type `DATE`. The tricky line is

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColDate", dtpDate.Value.Date);
```

Note that since the underlying column is of type `DATE`, I use the `DateTime.Date` property value, which is necessary for the query to work properly. Here is the full `Form` code:

```cs
using MySqlConnector;
using System.Data;

namespace MariaDbTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strSql = $"Select * From TblEvent Where ColDate = @ColDate";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = GetDataTable(strSql);
        }

        private DataTable? GetDataTable(string strSql)
        {
            using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(strSql, connection))
                    {
                        // This is the critical line.
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColDate", dtpDate.Value.Date);

                        var dataTable = new DataTable();
                        using (var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                        }
                        return dataTable;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Connection error: {ex.Message}");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            string server = "127.0.0.1";
            string database = "test";
            string user = "root";
            string password = "sa";
            return $"Server={server};Database={database};User={user};Password={password};";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but this only helps where the case is only one column in a GridView. I've got dates only to work with this query in my code, but searching with strings only returns empty rows.

`string upit = "SELECT * FROM radninalog WHERE opisNaloga LIKE @OpisNaloga AND inzenjerNaloga LIKE @InzenjerNaloga AND datumNaloga = @DatumNaloga OR (planiraniPocDatum = @PlaniraniPocDatum OR planiraniKrajDatum = @PlaniraniKrajDatum OR stvarniPocDatum = @StvarniPocDatum OR stvarniKrajDatum = @StvarniKrajDatum)";`

Comment: To run the query successfully with my approach, please 1) Check that *all* of your Date columns are of type DATE in MariaDB. 2) Use `DateTimePicker.Value.Date` for *all* date parameters in your `AddWithValue()` lines. 3) Double check your AND/OR logic in SQL. If you still have problems then try constructing your date SQL clauses incrementally. (Start with only one date filter, make sure you execute it correctly and then add the other date filters.)

Comment: The third approach was a success, thank you very much!